# Changing from recursion to iteration

Tags: algorithm, optimization, recursion, iteration

I have my function that needs changing to iteration, because of very slow executing of it.
There are two recursive calls, depends which condition is true.

It's something like this:
(I have static array of classes outside function, let's say data)

```
void func(int a, int b, int c, int d) {
    //something
    //non-recursive
    //here..

    for (i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
        if (!data[i].x) {
            data[i].x = 1;
            if (a == data[i].value1)
                func(data[i].value2,b,c,d);
            else if (a == data[i].value2)
                func(data[i].value1,b,c,d);

            data[i].x = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

!!
EDIT: Here is my algorithm: http://pastebin.com/F7UfzfHv
Function searches for every paths from one point to another in graph, but returns (to an array) only one path in which are only unique vertices.
!!

And I know that good way to manage that is to use stack... But I don't know how. Could someone give me a hint about it?

Comment: FYI, recursion uses a (call) stack. Run away recursion causes the name of this site... stack overflow error

Comment: Is this your actual implementation of the recursive method? If not, show it to us, because what I see here grossly violates all base principles of recursion. Namely, there is no base case that will cascade the recursion, e.g. no `if (x == y) return z;`, individual iterations don't address a specific subset of data and overlap, i.e. you're potentially iterating over the entire length of `data` on every iteration.

Comment: What are you trying to do in this method? The generic "change recursion to iteration" change will have almost identical running time.

Comment: This algorithm searches for every possible paths in graph, but with my modifications, it returns only one path

Answer (score 0):

There is a good possibility that your function might be computing the same thing again and again, which in technical terms is called as `overlapping sub-problems`(if you are familiar with the `dynamic programming` then you might know). First try to identify whether that is the case or not. Since you haven't told anything about what function do and I can't tell the exact problem.

Also the thing you are talking about using a `stack` is not of great use since recursion uses a stack internally. Using external stack instead of internal is more error prone is not of great use.